# How is it possible for a 12000 mAh battery pack to power a DC motor that requires 70 amps of current?

Tags: power, batteries, current

I have a DC motor: [DC Motor Link](https://propulsionboards.com/collections/motors/products/belt-motor-6374-190kv)

And a battery: [Battery Link](https://diyelectricskateboard.com/products/electric-skateboard-battery-epower-pack-12s4p?aff=3)

The motor says it requires a continuous ~79 amps of current. The battery says it gives 12 amp hours per charge.

I don't understand how it is possible for this battery to supply this dc motor without the battery dying very quickly. If the battery is only able to supply 12 amps per hour, but the motor requires 79 amps to operate continuously.

What am I missing here? Why does this work? According to the video I was watching this battery would last up to 30 miles on an electric longboard.

Comment: Range varies with speed/acceleration. Higher speed and aggressive acceleration (and terrain) affect battery drain. 79 amps may be peak current, but average current may be much less. We need more info to make a truly informed answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The motor says it requires a continuous ~79 amps of current.

The link says that maximum current is 79 amps, which is probably the most it can take without damage.  Continuous current almost certainly has to be much lower.

> If the battery is only able to supply 12 amps per hour

The unit is amps-hours, not amps per hour.  12 amp-hours is 12 amps for 1 hour, 24 amps for 30 minutes, 48 amps for 15 minutes, etc.

In this case though Google says those cells are rated for 15 amp continuous discharge (although they give peak up to 20A), and there is 4 in parallel according to your link, so you should limit current to 60 amps continuous, and indeed your link says the pack is rated for 60A continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The current a motor takes depends upon the load.

That motor can take up to 79Amps (the link states 85A) but the amount of effort to drive the skateboard must typically be such that the current is much much less.

If the board can do 20 mph it would take 1 1/2 hours to do 30 miles. The current under those conditions must average about 8A.